# How can I get value of element custom attribute with Watir

Tags: html, internet-explorer, watir

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
<input custom_attribute="so cool" type="text" />
```

I would like to get value of `custom_attribute` using [Watir](http://watir.com/).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
browser.text_field(:index, 1).attribute_value("custom_attribute")
#=> "so cool"
```

Sources:

- http://www.mail-archive.com/wtr-general%40rubyforge.org/msg06769.html
- http://rdoc.info/gems/watir/1.6.6/Watir/Element#attribute_value-instance_method
- https://github.com/watir/watir-classic/blob/master/lib/watir-classic/element.rb
- http://zeljkofilipin.com/watir-select-element-using-custom-attribute/

Comment: Unfortunately, The last 3 links on this answer for Watir documentation are dead links. I can't do it at the moment, but can someone provide updated links?

Comment: AMAZING!! you saved my life