# How to display attributes

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I have four radio buttons:

```
<div class="x1-radio">
    <input id = " " type="radio" name=" " value="12345">
        <span class=" ">Radio 1 - Good Luck</span>
<div class="x1-radio">
    <input id = " " type="radio" name=" " value="12345">
        <span class=" ">Radio 2 - Good Luck</span>
<div class="x1-radio">
    <input id = " " type="radio" name=" " value="12346">
        <span class=" ">Radio 3 - Good Luck</span>
<div class="x1-radio">
    <input id = " " type="radio" name=" " value="12347">
        <span class=" ">Radio 4 - Good Luck</span>
```

Since these are radio buttons, I can select one at a time. I know how to select the radio button using xpath:

```
nPath = '//*[@class="x1-radio"]//span[text() = "Radio 1 - Good Luck"]'
browser.element(:xpath, nPath).fire_event "onclick"
```

A button is selected at this point. What I want to know is how I can display the attributes in the "input" tag one by one to screen.

I found some info here:
[How can I get value of element custom attribute with Watir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443455/how-can-i-get-value-of-element-custom-attribute-with-watir)
but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 2):

This should display value of `value` attribute for each `input` element:

```
browser.inputs.each {|input| p input.value}
```

Something like this should display the same information but only for selected radio button(s):

```
browser.inputs.each {|input| p input.value if input.checked}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would you display ONLY the value of selected radio button "input" tag.

Comment: Do you know which button is selected, or do you have to inspect the page?

Comment: I can't tell which button is selected.  How to inspect the page?  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I am short on time now, take a look at my updated answer, something like that should work.

Comment: I added a '?' at the end to your code and it worked like a charm.  Thanks a lot for your help.