# How to read values of "data-contents"-attributes from spans with watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, watir-classic

I need to read the value of the attribute named "data-contents" from all the spans in a particular page

```
<span tabindex="0" title="" class="text-warning  ng-isolate-scope" role="button" data-original-title="" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-html="true" data-contents="If you are not sure which type of occupation in the list to choose, please call us on (852) 2884 8888 and we'll be happy to help you." data-content="If you are not sure which type of occupation in the list to choose, please call us on (852) 2884 8888 and we'll be happy to help you." data-da-popover="" data-da-popover-id="daPopover1455178167018" data-container="body" data-trigger="focus"><img src="/app/ui/images/question-icon.png">          </span>
```

I have written the following code,

```
  b.spans.each do |span|
        puts span.data-contents
  end
```

But it throws this error ': undefined local variable or method `contents' for main:Object (NameError)'

Can anyone please help me to read the value of this data-content?

Comment: Probably with the `attribute`-accessor as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443455/how-can-i-get-value-of-element-custom-attribute-with-watir ?

Comment: Yeah , that's great, It's works, thanks.

Comment: then lets close as duplicate

Comment: Yes sure, thanks for directing me there.

Comment: For html5 valid attributes (like 'data-*'), Justin's answer below should be preferred over the attribute_value method.

Comment: @titusfortner Merely because it is cleaner, or because it is somehow better/works more efficiently?

Comment: It's just cleaner. It's a method missing for data- & aria- attributes that literally calls `attribute_value(method.gsub(/_/, '-'), *args)`

Comment: titusfortner, thanks, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get data, as well as aria, attributes just like other attributes. The only difference is that the method name uses underscores instead of dashes.

To get the data-contents attribute, you would do:

```
puts span.data_contents
```